# Duplicate array elements and append to the same array

Tags: php

is there a good way to duplicate the existing values in an array and append them to the same array? Here's what I can think pf

**PHP**

```
$names = array('Tom', 'Dick', 'Hairy');
$names_new = $names;
$duplication = 3;
for($i = 0; i < $duplication; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < count($names); $j++) {
        $names_new[] = $names[$j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$names = array('Tom', 'Dick', 'Hairy');
$names2 = array_merge($names, $names);
```

$names2 will contain the array you want.
Documentation: [array_merge](http://php.net/array_merge)